# method to certify the number of chiral carbons in fischer and haworth projection of glucose

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, stereochemistry

While reading some notes about Glucose and its various projections:

- Fischer Projection: 4 chiral centres

[image: Fischer]

- Haworth Projection: 5 chiral centres

[image: Haworth]

**My doubt is that is there any (specific) method (practical) to ascertain the number of chiral centres in both the forms.**

I know that more than 99.5% of glucose exists as Haworth Projection - Closed Ring Structure and hence Linear - Fischer Projection practically does not exist.

But it (linear ie open chain glucose) could be always isolated though difficult.

Thank you!

Comment: While alpha-D-glucose does primarily exist in the cyclic form,  it does not exist as a Haworth Projection since the ring is not planar.  The chair conformation is a more accurate description. https://www.google.com/search?q=alpha+glucose+structure&client=firefox-b-1-d&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=BsiLDcxZkenRdM%253A%252CI7n8CaCE0-at0M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQE6Wh8iXlK1MCwLjfv7RBUZiDfdw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG-9f3_MvhAhXRnuAKHdecC4IQ9QEwDHoECAoQBg#imgrc=BsiLDcxZkenRdM:

Comment: @user55119 : What you say is absolutely correct. But what my point is whether you consider simple closed ring or haworth projection or chair conformer of glucose it would be **immaterial while considering the number of chiral centres**, which is 5, in comparison to the chiral centre (**4**) in a linear representation of glucose. [chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Organic_Chemistry_with_a_Biological_Emphasis_(Soderberg)/Chapter_03%3A_Conformations_and_Stereochemistry/03.8%3A_Fischer_and_Haworth_projections) ..  bottom of this page...

Comment: It is just a matter of which representation you are talking about. There is no absolute answer. Fischer used the linear representation to distinguish amongst stereoisomers. It was a simplification of Van't Hoff's more complex representation.